# query to add string to the existing data(string) in parse database objective c

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I am just wondering if there is any query to add string into parse database cell(which is already a string type, of course!).

Example:

Value already in database cell be : "abc"

Let "xyz" be the value I want to add to same parse database cell.

can I use any query to update the cell to : "abc xyz"

I do not want to get "abc" and add "xyz" to it and save back to the parse cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to query the objects, update them and then save them. You might create a cloud background job to do that, but that is the required process. Parse isn't using some kind of SQL DB in the background, and you can't directly interact with the DB anyway.